# How to get the element using ref in vuejs for shepperd

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am using shepperd for my guide tour in vue. Here is the documentation: https://shepherdjs.dev/

I created component for it:

```
<template>
  <div></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Guide',

  props: {
    element: {
      type: Object,
      required: true,
    },

    title: {
      type: String,
    },

    text: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },

    position: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const tour = this.$shepherd({
        defaultStepOptions: {
          cancelIcon: {
            enabled: true,
          },
          classes: 'class-1 class-2',
          scrollTo: { behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' },
        },
      });

      tour.addStep({
        attachTo: { element: this.element, on: this.position },
        title: this.title,
        text: this.text,
        buttons: [
          {
            action() {
              return this.back();
            },
            classes: 'shepherd-button-secondary',
            text: 'Back',
          },
          {
            action() {
              return this.next();
            },
            text: 'Next',
          },
        ],
        id: 'creating',
      });

      tour.start();
    });
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import '~shepherd.js/dist/css/shepherd.css';
</style>
```

Whats wrong in my code is, in parent component I cannot get the element. I am trying to do it with ref in vue. So I want to get the element of this button:

```
<button ref="button">
              Click
            </button>
beforeMount() {
    this.element = this.$refs.button;
  },
```

But it is getting null all the time. How can I get the element of the button?

Comment: Am I missing something? `ref="button"` ... `this.$refs.upload` ... button, upload .... they both have 6 letters, both have a u and an o ... other than that, it's like they are two completely different words

Comment: I changed the code when I ask question

Comment: oh, wait, I see the problem `beforeMount` ... the element probably doesn't exist yet

Comment: `$refs` cannot exist `beforeMount`. Because the component has not yet been mounted. Mounting means adding to DOM. `$refs` can only be accessed after component has been `mounted`.

Answer (score 1):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

If you want to access the DOM element, you should put the code in `mounted` hooks.

```
mounted() {
    this.element = this.$refs.button;
}
```

Note: mounted does not guarantee that all child components have also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been rendered, you can use `vm.$nextTick` inside of mounted